# Tikzpicture for BER graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have very simple question but It probably does not have easy answer. I am using the following BER diagram but I will welcome another version, improvements or suggestion for better graph.

[image: Current graph]

Thank you very much for each suggestion or different type for BER.

My code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=7cm,width=10cm,xlabel=EDFA output power (dBm),ylabel=Q factor (---),legend pos=south west, grid=major]

\addplot[color=blue,mark=x,only marks] coordinates {
(   18  ,   13  )
(   19  ,   12.9    )
(   20  ,   12.3    )
(   21  ,   11.9    )
(   22  ,   11.7    )
(   23  ,   11.4    )
(   24  ,   11.1    )
(   25  ,   11  )
(   26  ,   11  )
(   27  ,   10.9    )
};

\addplot[color=black,mark=o,only marks] coordinates {
(   18  ,   13  )
(   19  ,   12.6    )
(   20  ,   12.2    )
(   21  ,   12.2    )
(   22  ,   11.7    )
(   23  ,   11.1    )
(   24  ,   11  )
(   25  ,   10.8    )
(   26  ,   11  )
(   27  ,   10.9    )
};

\addplot[color=orange,mark=halfcircle*,only marks] coordinates {
(   18  ,   13.1    )
(   19  ,   13.1    )
(   20  ,   13  )
(   21  ,   12.9    )
(   22  ,   12.4    )
(   23  ,   11.7    )
(   24  ,   11.6    )
(   25  ,   10.8    )
(   26  ,   10.7    )
(   27  ,   10.3    )
};
\addlegendentry{200\,ns, 10\,kHz}
\addlegendentry{500\,ns, 10\,kHz}
\addlegendentry{800\,ns, 10\,kHz}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the source code, my mistake.

Comment: Unrelated to latex (which is hard to comment on without code), but I would avoid using yellow for markers. This will be hard to see in case someone prints your graph in black and white or if you intend to show it in a presentation. To make the markers easier to distinguished I would use three different geometrical shapes, e.g. replace the half-filled circles by squares or something.

Comment: I am looking for different style or graph, do not need to follow "my style" as is above.

Comment: Personally I would remove the background grid for a better information-ink-ratio

Comment: What is a "BER" diagram ?

Comment: I second @BambOo

Comment: @BambOo Wikipedia thinks it might be "bit error rate"

Comment: @samcarter I see. I was about to recommend using a MUC diagram because it will take a while before BER is finished. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Will Davids picture mode airplanes be allowed to land on a tikz drawn airport?

Comment: If I understand it the question is how to draw a better graph, *but* what does **better** mean?

Comment: The graph looks OK to me. And I agree with @Andrew that, as long as you do not provide any concrete ideas what you want to have improved, it will be hard to guess what you want. (Please note that [my crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen.)

Comment: Hello, I was thinking about diferent graph style, I am using this graph so long however it is proper. I wanted to know your "proper" graph for bit error rate.